# K shortest paths - any relation between K and % of graph nodes in discovered paths?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, shortest-path

Let's say I have a graph with $N$ nodes, $A$ arcs and an average branching factor $b$.  I want to find the $K$ shortest paths between two nodes.

Is there some relation (even approximate is fine) that expresses the dependency between the parameter $K$ and percentage of nodes included in the paths discovered by running the algorithm ([Yen's loopless KSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yen's_algorithm))?

For example, in a graph of 20 nodes, the ($1st$) shortest path from node $1$ to $12$ is $1-4-7-12$, while the $2nd$ shortest path is $1-4-6-9-12$.

So for $K=1$, the discovered path contains $4/20 = 20\%$ of the nodes in the graph. For $K=2$, the two paths contain $6/20 = 30\%$ of the nodes. This relation between $K$ and the percentage is what I'm looking for.

Comment: "by running the algorithm" - which algorithm are you planning to use?  Also, what are your thoughts?  What have you tried, and where did you get stuck?

Comment: Since even Dijkstra et al. *always* "explore" *all* nodes -- and they have to! -- I think it's unlikely that a k-shortest-paths algorithm can make do with less.

Comment: @Raphael: anyway, the question makes a lot of sense in the average case. I mean, there is certainly a relationship between the number of shortest paths to compute and the extra amount of work to do. I think we know nothing about this and the answer might depend on parameters other than those mentioned in the question. Anyway, devil0150 I would strongly recommend you to edit your question and to post the question as a relationship between $K$ and the extra amount of work (which actually involves re-expansions instead of generations!)

Comment: What is a *branching factor* of a graph? I know what a branching factor in a tree is, but I don't know what does it mean in a generic graph!

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me the relation depends purely on how the graph is made. Think about a cycle. The shortest path between two adjacent vertices contains 2 vertices while the second contains n vertices